1.8 inch Waveshare LCD screen showing wrong colors on Raspberry Pi Pico W
I recently connected a Raspberry Pi Pico W to a 1.8 LCD screen from Waveshare. The screen seems to work fine and is quite responsive, but the colors seem to be wildly different from what is coded. For example, LCD.BLUE, which should display blue, is displaying yellow. I used the demo code from Waveshare which is given below.
from machine import Pin,SPI,PWM
import framebuf
import time

BL = 13
DC = 8
RST = 12
MOSI = 11
SCK = 10
CS = 9


class LCD_1inch8(framebuf.FrameBuffer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 160
        self.height = 128
        
        self.cs = Pin(CS,Pin.OUT)
        self.rst = Pin(RST,Pin.OUT)
        
        self.cs(1)
        self.spi = SPI(1)
        self.spi = SPI(1,1000_000)
        self.spi = SPI(1,10000_000,polarity=0, phase=0,sck=Pin(SCK),mosi=Pin(MOSI),miso=None)
        self.dc = Pin(DC,Pin.OUT)
        self.dc(1)
        self.buffer = bytearray(self.height * self.width * 2)
        super().__init__(self.buffer, self.width, self.height, framebuf.RGB565)
        self.init_display()
        

        self.WHITE =   0xFFFF
        self.BLACK  =  0x0000
        self.GREEN   =  0x001F
        self.BLUE    =  0xF800
        self.RED   = 0x07E0

        
    def write_cmd(self, cmd):
        self.cs(1)
        self.dc(0)
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(bytearray([cmd]))
        self.cs(1)

    def write_data(self, buf):
        self.cs(1)
        self.dc(1)
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(bytearray([buf]))
        self.cs(1)

    def init_display(self):
        """Initialize dispaly"""  
        self.rst(1)
        self.rst(0)
        self.rst(1)
        
        self.write_cmd(0x36);
        self.write_data(0x70);
        
        self.write_cmd(0x3A);
        self.write_data(0x05);

         #ST7735R Frame Rate
        self.write_cmd(0xB1);
        self.write_data(0x01);
        self.write_data(0x2C);
        self.write_data(0x2D);

        self.write_cmd(0xB2);
        self.write_data(0x01);
        self.write_data(0x2C);
        self.write_data(0x2D);

        self.write_cmd(0xB3);
        self.write_data(0x01);
        self.write_data(0x2C);
        self.write_data(0x2D);
        self.write_data(0x01);
        self.write_data(0x2C);
        self.write_data(0x2D);

        self.write_cmd(0xB4); #Column inversion
        self.write_data(0x07);

        #ST7735R Power Sequence
        self.write_cmd(0xC0);
        self.write_data(0xA2);
        self.write_data(0x02);
        self.write_data(0x84);
        self.write_cmd(0xC1);
        self.write_data(0xC5);

        self.write_cmd(0xC2);
        self.write_data(0x0A);
        self.write_data(0x00);

        self.write_cmd(0xC3);
        self.write_data(0x8A);
        self.write_data(0x2A);
        self.write_cmd(0xC4);
        self.write_data(0x8A);
        self.write_data(0xEE);

        self.write_cmd(0xC5); #VCOM
        self.write_data(0x0E);

        #ST7735R Gamma Sequence
        self.write_cmd(0xe0);
        self.write_data(0x0f);
        self.write_data(0x1a);
        self.write_data(0x0f);
        self.write_data(0x18);
        self.write_data(0x2f);
        self.write_data(0x28);
        self.write_data(0x20);
        self.write_data(0x22);
        self.write_data(0x1f);
        self.write_data(0x1b);
        self.write_data(0x23);
        self.write_data(0x37);
        self.write_data(0x00);
        self.write_data(0x07);
        self.write_data(0x02);
        self.write_data(0x10);

        self.write_cmd(0xe1);
        self.write_data(0x0f);
        self.write_data(0x1b);
        self.write_data(0x0f);
        self.write_data(0x17);
        self.write_data(0x33);
        self.write_data(0x2c);
        self.write_data(0x29);
        self.write_data(0x2e);
        self.write_data(0x30);
        self.write_data(0x30);
        self.write_data(0x39);
        self.write_data(0x3f);
        self.write_data(0x00);
        self.write_data(0x07);
        self.write_data(0x03);
        self.write_data(0x10);

        self.write_cmd(0xF0); #Enable test command
        self.write_data(0x01);

        self.write_cmd(0xF6); #Disable ram power save mode
        self.write_data(0x00);

            #sleep out
        self.write_cmd(0x11);
        #DEV_Delay_ms(120);

        #Turn on the LCD display
        self.write_cmd(0x29);

    def show(self):
        self.write_cmd(0x2A)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0x01)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0xA0)
        
        
        
        self.write_cmd(0x2B)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0x02)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0x81)
        
        self.write_cmd(0x2C)
        
        self.cs(1)
        self.dc(1)
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(self.buffer)
        self.cs(1)
  
if __name__=='__main__':
    pwm = PWM(Pin(BL))
    pwm.freq(1000)
    pwm.duty_u16(32768)#max 65535

    LCD = LCD_1inch8()
    #color BRG
    LCD.fill(LCD.WHITE)
 
    LCD.show()
    
    LCD.fill_rect(0,0,160,20,LCD.RED)
    LCD.rect(0,0,160,20,LCD.RED)
    LCD.text("Raspberry Pi Pico",2,8,LCD.WHITE)
    
    LCD.fill_rect(0,20,160,20,LCD.BLUE)
    LCD.rect(0,20,160,20,LCD.BLUE)
    LCD.text("PicoGo",2,28,LCD.WHITE)
    
    LCD.fill_rect(0,40,160,20,LCD.GREEN)
    LCD.rect(0,40,160,20,LCD.GREEN)
    LCD.text("Pico-LCD-1.8",2,48,LCD.WHITE)
    
    LCD.fill_rect(0,60,160,10,0X1F3F)
    LCD.rect(0,60,160,10,0X1F3F)
    LCD.fill_rect(0,70,160,10,0x2ECC40)
    LCD.rect(0,70,160,10,0x2ECC40)
    LCD.fill_rect(0,80,160,10,0xFF4136)
    LCD.rect(0,80,160,10,0xFF4136)
    LCD.fill_rect(0,90,160,10,0xFF851B)
    LCD.rect(0,90,160,10,0xFF851B)
    LCD.fill_rect(0,100,160,10,0X39CCCC)
    LCD.rect(0,100,160,10,0X39CCCC)
    LCD.fill_rect(0,110,160,10,0XB10DC9)
    LCD.rect(0,110,160,10,0XB10DC9)
    LCD.fill_rect(0,120,160,10,0XAAAAAA)
    LCD.rect(0,120,160,10,0XAAAAAA)
    
    currentTime = time.localtime()
    
    print(currentTime)



            
            
    LCD.show()
    time.sleep(1)
    LCD.fill(0xFFFF)

An image of the resulting color is given below.

Is there some line in the code that is inverting the colors or something?
UPDATE: So, this isn't exactly a solution, but I did find out that if I used the code below, which is explained in more detail in this link, then I can use this color() function to get accurate RGB colors on the screen. I'm still not sure why the hexadecimal color system does not work.
def colour(R,G,B): # Convert RGB888 to RGB565
    return (((G&0b00011100)<<3) +((B&0b11111000)>>3)<<8) + (R&0b11111000)+((G&0b11100000)>>5)

